# Geofence - permission location crash

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-geofence

I used geofences in my application.
I have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in my manifest.
My targetSdkVersion is 22

On some devices with android 6 everything is ok.

But on some other with android 6, like NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet I have crash because this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Geofence usage requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzl.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznt$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.zzf(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoc.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoh.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzof.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzf.addGeofences(Unknown Source)
at mypackage.location.LocationHelper.addGeofences(LocationHelper.java:222)
at mypackage.location.PoiGeofencesHelper.addGeofences(PoiGeofencesHelper.java:42)
at mypackage.fragment.LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.addGeofences(LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.java:763)
at mypackage.fragment.LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.onLoadFinished(LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.java:471)
at mypackage.fragment.LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.onLoadFinished(LocalTitleRecyclerFragment.java:80)
at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:479)
at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:447)
at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:105)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:37)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:249)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:77)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:466)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(ModernAsyncTask.java:48)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:483)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5460)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: why does this surprise you? Its android 6

Comment: But if I have permission in manifest and target 22 I don´t need runtime permission.  @TimCastelijns

Comment: If it's not true all applications thats not target 23 stop working on all android 6 devices. And It's not true. @TimCastelijns

Comment: Even if you target API < 23, nothing prevents the user to disable location permission in its app settings. Setting the target less than 23 only enables the permission by default.